# Android Product Flavors for Java Web Projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I am wondering if someone has tried to use Android Product Flavors for simple Java Web Projects (e.g. Spring Boot) and can show me the best approach to do that? 
We are using IntelliJ for web service development and it should reflect selected flavors in the same way as Android Studio does.

We don't want to use spring profiles, or have multiple branches to maintain.

Comment: Hey, did you find any answer for this?